# Define template variables without a class

Tags: c++, templates

I want to define template variables without a class, but MSVC++ does not accept it, and Googling around it seems to be incorrect according to the C++ standard:

```
template<CharType> static CharType hexDigits[17];
template<> char hexDigits[17] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
template<> wchar_t hexDigits[17] = L"0123456789ABCDEF";
```

These specialized variables will then be used from within a (non-specialized) template function.

So I'm forced to write it like this:

```
template<typename CharType> class dummyclass {
    static CharType hexDigits[17];
};
template<> char dummyclass<char>::hexDigits[17] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
template<> wchar_t dummyclass<wchar_t>::hexDigits[17] = L"0123456789ABCDEF";
```

Is there any way I can define these two variables *without* defining a dummy class?

Also, is there any good reason *why* the C++ standard does not allow the first piece of code? After all, template *functions* outside a class are permitted.

Comment: Because C++ does not have a notion of an "object template". Only class and function templates are part of the language.

Comment: In keeping with the standard library style, you would call it `HexDigits<T>::value`...

Comment: C++ templates were designed so the compiler could generate functions for arguments with various types during the compilation. For that purpose, templates for variables make no sense, because the variable type is defined and there would be nothing to generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also, is there any good reason why the C++ standard does not allow the first piece of code? After all, template functions outside a class are permitted.

Note that this:

```
template<CharType> static CharType hexDigits[17];
template<> char hexDigits[17] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
template<> wchar_t hexDigits[17] = L"0123456789ABCDEF";
```

has two symbols with different types but the same name: this can't possibly work, so the compiler would have to start mangling/decorating the names of variables like it already does for functions and classes.

In terms of implementing this cleanly, this looks like a trait to me ... if you don't mind getting a link error instead of a compile error, you can even skip the specialization and only declare the appropriate static members:

```
template <typename CharType> struct my_char_traits {
    static CharType hex_digits[17];
};

template<> char my_char_traits<char>::hex_digits[17] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
template<> wchar_t my_char_traits<wchar_t>::hex_digits[17] = L"0123456789ABCDEF";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only create a class template or struct or a function template.

Template variable's like you're trying to do is illegal in C++.

You'll have to create a class template and then use that.